# Строка запроса для MySQL в Delphi с более чем 255 символов. И проблема с кавычками

Tags: mysql, delphi

Вздумал вспомнить Delphi (8-лет его не трогал).
Делаю строку запроса:

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO exam_users (`family`, `name`,  `patronymic`, `birthdate`, `passport_serial`, `passport_number`,'
          +'`passport_date`, `organization`, `organization_code`, `programma`, `level`, `civilian_weapons`, `group`, `num_certificate`,'
          +'`date_certificate`, `date_exam`, `job`, `telephone`, `user_files`, `time_rec`, `date_rec`, `status`, `description`,)'
          +'VALUES  ('+Edit1.text+', '+Edit2.text+', '+Edit3.text+', '+Edit4.text+', '+Edit5.text+', '+Edit6.text+', '+Edit7.text+', '+Edit8.text+','
          +''+Edit9.text+', '+Edit10.text+', '+Edit11.text+', '+Edit12.text+', '+Edit13.text+', '+Edit14.text+', '+Edit15.text+', '+Edit16.text+', '+Edit3.text+','
          +''+Edit17.text+', '+Edit18.text+', '+Edit19.text+', '+Edit20.text+', '+Edit21.text+', '+Edit22.text+', '+Edit23.text+'');
```

Брал со своего рабочего PHP-кода.
Далее вычитал про параметры, так как с экранированием кавычек в Delphi видать туго и сделал такой вариант:

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO exam_users (`family`, `name`, `patronymic`, `birthdate`) VALUES    (:family, :name, :patronymic, :birthdate');
          Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('family').Value:= Edit1.text;
          Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= Edit2.text;
          Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('patronymic').Value:= Edit3.text;
          Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('birthdate').Value:= Edit4.text;
```

И всё равно вываливается ошибка (Exception):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно что на `Parameters.ParamByName` перешли - так гораздо более читаемый и безопасный код. Ограничение на количество символов тут вроде не при чем.

Comment: Не знаю, что вы рабочего нашли в своих SQL-запросах - оба с грубыми синтаксическими ошибками. В обоих не закрыта скобка секции VALUES, в первом ещё и "`description`,)" - запятой здесь быть не должно.

Comment: @Давайте спорить не будете, а то я приведу код и вы проспорите. Код который на PHP. Отлаженный и рабочий. Сами знаете, что в PHP используется стиль `'$name',`. А после discription запятая осталась от сокращения переменной `'$ip_address` при переносе из PHP. (А это уже действительно моё упущение). И скобку тоже видать потерял. P.S. Я же написал - 8 лет Delphi не открывал. И занимаюсь целым учебным центром, двумя порталами, а не одним программированием. Кризис знаете ли...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скобку не закрыли:

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO exam_users (`family`, `name`, `patronymic`, `birthdate`) VALUES (:family, :name, :patronymic, :birthdate)');
```

Comment: спасибо Вам за внимательность. Видать запутался с этими кавычками и переносом их PHP.

Answer (score 0):

И ещё одно простое решение по кавычкам.
Как и писал лет 8-мь не программировал на Delphi, но наработки остались.
И нашел в старом коде решение по кавычкам.
Всего лишь навсего обернуть переменные в `" "`:

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.add('INSERT INTO exam_users (`family`,  `name`, `patronymic`,   `birthdate`)'
              +' VALUES ("'+Edit1.text+'", "'+Edit2.text+'", "'+Edit3.text+'", "'+Edit4.text+'")');
```

Comment: Через параметры все решается намного проще и без изврата.